# Is it possible to disable a JSpinner down arrow button? How?

Tags: java, swing, button, jspinner

I have a JSpinner which starts at 0 and when its value is 0, its down arrow button should be disabled so the value does not change. Does anyone knows how to disable a button in a JSpinner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a SpinnerModel. E.g. the following line limits the values between 0 and MAX_VALUE (i.e. values are bounded by zero from below). Arguments are: value, min, max, step_size.

```
JSpinner jSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1));
```

Note: the button is not disabled actually, but does not decrease the value.

Comment: By the way... the button is "quite disbled" since it cannot be pressed and its overlay functionality is disabled